# Confusion with definition of irreducible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

An integer $p$ is said to be irreducible if whenever $p=ab$ then $a $ or $b$ is $1$ or $-1$.

Then we define an irreducible element $p$ in a commutative ring $R$ with unity as:

> $1)$ $p \neq 0$ and $p$ isn't unit, and
>   $2)$ whenever $p=ab$ then one of $a$ and $b$ is a unit.

I can't understand $2)$. Shouldn't it be that one of $a$ and $b$ is unity instead of *unit*, if we see this from definition of an integer...

I can't understand. Please help.

Comment: (-1) is unity? (-1) is unit?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla but how does it sove my doubt??

Comment: What do you mean by "unity" and "unit"? Do you have clear definitions of the two terms? Because everything depends on those definitions, and without knowing what you are working with I can't understand how you are getting confused.

Comment: @MarkBennet The definition of unity states that it is that element of ring s.t. its multiplication by an element $ a $ of ring gives $a$ .The definition of unit states it to be that element in ring $R$ s.t. its multiplicative inverse exists in ring... but after knowing this how can I solve my doubt ?

Answer (score 2):

If the definition of unity you have helpfully put in your comments is applied in the integers, consider the number $7=1\times 7=7\times 1=-7\times -1=-1\times -7$

It clearly has factorisations involving $-1$, and $-1$ is a unit but not a unity: note that $-1\times 7=-7\neq 7$.

For the integers, therefore, we already need a definition of irreducible which goes beyond "unity" to the beginnings of the idea of "unit" - we need to include $-1$ as well as $1$ otherwise the definition does not work as we would like and every line needs a comment on $-1$ as an exception.

The idea of unit is generalised in other contexts to all elements with a multiplicative inverse. The point is that the definition is not useful unless we pick out the units in this way.

Comment: alright I understood this for integers ,thatmeans similarly in case of any comm. ring with unity also, I need to see this definition in terms of units only..

Answer (score 1):

Saying "one of a and b is a unit" is the same as saying "one of a and b is +1 or -1." Note: the multiplicative identity (typically 1) and the negative multiplicative identity (-1) are ALWAYS units. A unit is simply an invertible element of a ring.

Comment: a unity is always a unit ,but how is converse true as your first statement says?